# How to do routing in react native

Tags: react-native

I am working on the React native project, I am trying to do routing in my application but I don't
Know how to do routing in React native application. But I tried somewhat in my application.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './android/app/src/Components/Navbar/Navbar';

const App = () => {
  return <Navbar />;
};

export default App;
```

This is Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Home from '../../Screens/Home/Home';
import About from '../../Screens/About/About';
import Services from '../../Screens/Services/Services';
import Contact from '../../Screens/Contact/Contact';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Navbar = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
<View>
<View style={[styles.navScreens]}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
        <Text>About</Text>
        <Text>Services</Text>
        <Text>Contact</Text>
      </View>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Services" component={Services} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navIconsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },

  navScreens: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingTop: 725,
  },
});

export default Navbar;
```

This is Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home works</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

This is About.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const About = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>About works</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default About;
```

This is Services.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Services = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Services works</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Services;
```

This is Contact.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Contact works</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

This is Package.json

```
{
  "name": "emtelproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.9",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Exactly what I am looking for when the App complied successfully by default it has to be in Home component and it has to show Home works on the screen.

Comment: use a package named stackNavigator , it provides aviation for react native apps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
```

Comment: Hi @Vladimir I tried your code but I am not able to see Home works content on my screen ?

Answer (score 0):

Your navBar should be like this

```
 const Stack = createStackNavigator();
 const Navbar = ({navigation}) => {
   return (             
       <NavigationContainer>
         <Stack.Navigator  initialRouteName="Home">
           <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
           <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
           <Stack.Screen name="Services" component={Services} />
           <Stack.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
         </Stack.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
   );
 };
export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Hi @Ravi, I tried your code, But I am not able to see content Home works, this Home works content is in Home component.

Comment: can you share your entire code. app.js and navBar.js file

Comment: I already shared my entire code of App.js and  Navbar.js  in My question please go through it once. Thank you very much